# FastReport 5 Master/Detail band print master on new page

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I created a report with a master band and a detail band, both connected to datasource and table. The 2 tables are master/detail. The first table(Table1) has 1 record and the second(Table2) has 2 records. Now I can print one page for each record in Table2, but the master band is only on the first page. I need to print the master band on the second page too. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Delphi XE8 and FastReport 5. I used to do it in Rave and Delphi 7 but I can't find how to do it with FastReport.

Comment: I haven't looked for a while into FastReport but isn't it possible to put your master table into the Page Header?

Comment: The master band does not have a ReprintOnNewPage property but a group header does.  Maybe if you could put the printable controls from your master band into a group header, that would get you what you need.

Comment: @jrodenhi  Yes if I put the printable controls into a group header it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what you can do is, is loop through the records and generate one report for each row and then concatenate the reports together with preparereport(False) and then once you have have all the reports made you can just use Showpreparedreport